# Identity Scaffolding on Ubuntu 20.04 using incorrect file paths dotnet 5

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, ubuntu-20.04, asp.net-core-scaffolding

Output of `dotnet --info`:

```yaml
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.101
 Commit:    d05174dc5a

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  20.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.20.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.101/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.1
  Commit:  b02e13abab

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.404 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  5.0.101 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.10 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.10 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

### Steps to reproduce:

1. Install the code generator: `dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator`
2. Create a project to scaffold into `dotnet new webapp --auth Individual -o WebApp1`
3. cd into the new project directory
4. Install Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
5. Build the project to make sure everything works (build OK)
6. run scaffold :
   `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc WebApp1.Data.ApplicationDbContext --files "Account.Register;Account.Login;Account.Logout;Account.RegisterConfirmation"`

### Expected behavior:

All Identity.UI Razor Pages are scaffolded into the project

### Actual behavior:

A fatal error indicating a file was not found:

```sh
Account.RegisterConfirmation"
Building project ...
Finding the generator 'identity'...
Running the generator 'identity'...
A file matching the name Account.Register.cs.cshtml was not found within any of the folders: 
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b__6_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
RunTime 00:00:09.87
```

### Additional information about the project being scaffolded, such as:

- Target framework(s): **net5.0**
- Package version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.All (if applicable): **5.0.1**
- Package version of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design - this may be added to your project by scaffolding: **5.0.1**

Comment: related issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26524

Comment: @vladimir thanx for your hint

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue with Omnisharp not being able to generate my razor pages. The link @vladimir provided, I found that running this command for 6.0.2 worked for me.

```
dotnet tool update dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator -g --version 6.0.2
```

You can see what versions you have `dotnet --info` but I just did it for 6.0.2, and everything is back online.